# OBD-II - Multiple Devices Querying the BUS

Tags: obd-ii

Finding answers is like pulling teeth :) We have a program that queries the OBD Bus. 010D (vehicle speed) to be specific. We have found that when there are other devices on the Bus that query the OBD that out software no longer works.

General consensus is that only one device can query but.... that is just general consensus. A few people have come back with things like "you need to know what the other devices are" or "you have to filter out the other devices", things like that. The problem is that the few that say it can be down aren't specific enough.

So... can it be done and, if so, what are the specifics? How do you do it?

Comment: Do you have a dump of the [CAN] bus traffic?  Is your device acting as a tester on the bus? What's the other device?

Comment: What do you mean is my device acting as a tester? The other device(s) can be anything. What we are trying to do is get out software to work no matter what else the customer puts on the OBD Bus.